# transaction tutorial - test rollback

Tags: java, spring, transactions, dao, jdbctemplate

I am trying to learn how to use transaction in java spring.  I am a java novice so please bear with me :-)  The unit test im trying to achieve below is testing: 
rollback if a runtime exception is thrown.

The problem im having is a 
java.lang.NullPointerException?

Ok here goes..  I have stripped out some code to help improve readability

**TutorialTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class, loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class TutorialTest {

    @Autowired
    private Dao dao;


    @Test
    public void that_if_a_runtime_exception_is_thrown_transaction_rolledback(){

        User u = new User();
        u.setUsername("FAIL_TEST");
        u.setPhone("0161");
        u.setEmail("FAIL_TEST@gmail.com");
        //dao.addUser(u);  // -- this will insert if uncommented out so I know it works

        OuterService os  = new OuterService();
        os.addUserThrowError(u);

    }
}
```

**OuterService.java**

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class, loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class OuterService {

    @Autowired
    private Dao dao;

    @Transactional
    public void addUserThrowError(User user) throws RuntimeException{

        dao.addUser(user);  // gives me a java.lang.NullPointerException?

        throw new RuntimeException("This should roll back DB entry");
    }

}
```

Beans are declared in

**AppConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(value = {"com.training.spring.tx.tutorial.dao",
                        "com.training.spring.tx.tutorial.service"})
public class AppConfig {

    public DataSource dataSource() {

        // Create a BasicDataSource object and configure database

        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/spring_training_tx");
        dataSource.setUsername("training");
        dataSource.setPassword("training");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(){
        return new JdbcTemplate(transactionManager().getDataSource());
    }

}
```

Comment: Spring is not involved in `new OuterService();`

Comment: Look into Javadoc. Spring has very good documentation. What does `@ContextConfiguration` do? How do you declare beans in Spring?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question to help improve it.   I also removed spring from the title.  I have included the beans declaration.

Comment: The answer is extremely simple: _Spring is not involved in new OuterService();_ and therefore doesn't autowire anything into that object. The explanation is longer. Read the Spring IoC documentation, which explains all of this.

Comment: I have had a look at the documentation and im not any closer to figuring out what I need to do?  From your replies I gather I think I need to link new OuterService() with the beans config.  The bean examples on there are in XML and the ones ive been told to learn are not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to quote the [javadoc of `@ContextConfiguration`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html)

> `@ContextConfiguration` defines class-level metadata that is used to
>   determine how to load and configure an `ApplicationContext` for
>   integration tests.

Consider how you are using it on `OuterService`. Does it seem right? Is `OuterService` meant to be used to load and configure an `ApplicationCOntext` for integration tests? Unless I'm missing something essential, the answer is: No.

So what is `OuterService`? It's some kind of service. You seem to want to use it as a bean. What is a bean? A bean is an object whose lifecycle is managed by Spring. This includes instantiation of the bean class, initialization of the object, post processing, and, finally, destruction of the object.

If you created the object like so

```
OuterService os  = new OuterService();
```

then Spring is not involved. You created the object and there is no way for Spring to hook into that. You cannot therefore expect Spring to autowire its field

```
@Autowired
private Dao dao;
```

And since you haven't initialized the field, it remains `null`, which causes the `NullPointerException`.

So how do we get an `OuterService` bean, which *is* managed by Spring? You either declare a `@Bean` method for `OuterService` or you annotate `OuterService` with `@Component` or any of its specializations and component-scan the package it is in. You then inject the bean into any other bean that uses it. For example,

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class, loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class TutorialTest {

    @Autowired
    private Dao dao;

    @Autowired
    private OuterService os;
```

You can then use that variable directly.